# Visual Basic for Excel2010 code error

Tags: image, excel, excel-2010, vba

I need help with getting two different Drop down menus to work. Each menu item requires a choice that gives an answer back in the form of an image. I can get the 1st menu to work but the second one doesn't seem to work. I know I can't have two Sub worksheet_calculates with the same name but the range (f1:f18) gives an error also. The menus do the exact same thing but give answers in different cells. I have attached the code I am using in visual basic for Excel2010. If I delete the :f18 then the first menu works great. I hope I am conveying my desire and problem. Thanks

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim oPic As Picture
    Me.Pictures.Visible = False
    With Range("F1:F18")
        For Each oPic In Me.Pictures
            If oPic.Name = .Text Then
                oPic.Visible = True
                oPic.Top = .Top
                oPic.Left = .Left
                Exit For
            End If
        Next oPic
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you attempting to use a `Workbook Event`? Or is this supposed to be a macro assigned to the dropdown menus?

Comment: ? Good question. I have it set up with the pictures on the working sheet and the named drop down with a vlookup function. Each drop down menu item brings up a picture. This code is for the first drop down menu. I tried to set up a second dropdown menu to do the exact same thing but in cell F18 instead of F1. I could not do the same code and I could not figure out how to get the above code to allow this to work in both dropdown menus. I am barely functional in Excel and admit that I have piecemealed this from the "internet" and also the two books I have 2007 & 2010 excel. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Am I correct in my assumption that only one dropdown menu will be used at once? If a user clicks on one dropdown, you only want that dropdown to function - not both at the same time?

Comment: Arich- They will be used in order. Step one is to make a selection on dropdown #1, a picture will pop up next to that selection. Then Step two is to make a selection on dropdown #2. Which will in turn pop up a picture below the 1st picture. Both pictures will be seen and printable. Thank You again for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, based on what you've told me, I modified your code (see below).

**Tested and works in Excel 2010**

Whichever sheet you have your drop downs in, in the VBEditor, double-click on that sheet's name in the project explorer, then paste this code in that sheet module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'This line checks to see whether the cell that changed is F1 or F18.
If Intersect(Target, Range("A8,A11")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Dim oPic As Picture

'This line hides all the pictures on the sheet.
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Visible = False

'This line looks through all the pictures on the sheet and unhides the one _
'whose name matches the name in the drop down.
For Each oPic In ActiveSheet.Pictures
    If oPic.Name = Target.Value Then
        oPic.Visible = True
        If Target.Address = Range("A8").Address Then
            oPic.Top = Range("F1").Top
            oPic.Left = Range("F1").Left
        Else
            oPic.Top = Range("F18").Top
            oPic.Left = Range("F18").Left
        End If
        Exit For
    End If
Next oPic
End Sub
```

**Notes**
 This code will only work if you have `Events` enabled. A quick way to check this is to paste this in the Immediate Window and press `Enter` (`Ctrl+G` to open the Immediate Window):

```
?Application.EnableEvents
```

If the result says `True`, you're good to go. If it reads `False`, paste this in the Immediate Window and press `Enter`:

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

The `Target` you see in the code above refers to the cell in the worksheet whose value changed. Any time a value in any cell *in that sheet* changes, this code will fire. That's why I included the first `If Statement` at the beginning to check whether the cell that changed was `F1` or `F18`.

[See this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx) for more information on `Worksheet_Change Events`.
[See this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) for more intormation on `Target`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: ARich, I tried this and it didn't change anything. The names of the pictures show up in F1 or F18 but the pictures themselves do not appear. I double checked that Application events are set at true also.

Comment: Did you put the code in the sheet module or in a regular module? An easy way to test if the code is firing is to set a `Breakpoint` on the first line (the `If` statement) and then change the cell value on your sheet. To set a `Breakpoint`, put your cursor on the line you want the `Breakpoint` on and press `F9`. The line will have a red background.

Comment: I did the F9 test and it highlighted the If statement in red, then went to the sheet and ran the dropdown menu. It jumped to the formula on that line.

Comment: ( I deleted the previous code I had in the sheet module and pasted the code provided)

Comment: Ok, it sounds like it's working, which means that the loop isn't finding any pictures that match the name in your dropdown. Make sure that the names match. If they do, try stepping through the code with `F8` to see why the code is skipping your pictures. Other than that, it's really difficult for me to say why it isn't working since, as I mentioned above, this code worked when I tested it.

Comment: Just to make sure, I do insert the pictures in the cell where I would like them to popup, correct? Of course they are bigger than the actual cell but they are snapped to the cell in the left upper corners of the pictures.

Comment: It shouldn't matter where the pictures have been placed on the sheet. The code will always align them with the upper-left corner of the cell to the right of the dropdown.

Comment: Arich- Just in case, does it matter that I have the pictures popping into F1 & F18 but the drop downs are in Column A

Comment: Yes! That definitely changes things. Which cells are your dropdowns in?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified, the dropdowns are in A8 and A11. B column is being used to fill in the prices which are also affiliated with the drop downs. If necessary I can make the popup cells C1 & C18.

Comment: Ok, I've edited my answer to reflect dropdowns in `A8` and A11`. Test it out and let me know how it works.

Comment: It didn't work. However the pictures are all vanishing with any choice. That is one step closer than the last time. :) I double checked to make sure the pictures have corresponding names with the named drop down list. After inserting pictures the first choice on the drop down makes the pictures vanish and then when you choose an item from the drop down that should have an image they do not reappear.

Comment: Unfortunately since I can't see what's happening, I'm unable to offer any further assistance. I advise that you step through the code (use `F8`) and watch how the code reacts for each step. The code *should* work fine based on the info you've given. There may be other external forces at work here that I don't have visibility to. Let me know if you debug the code and figure out why it isn't working.